# Sharepoint group permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

I'm brand new to sharepoint and learning as I go and I'm needing to set up a new group that can only add/modify/delete documents. Now when I look at the permsissions when I add a new group it seems that everything is referring to web pages not documents. That's where I'm confused.

For instance, the Contribute permission is "Can view, add, update, and delete", but thats referring to web pages correct?

If I'm wanting a group to not be able to do anything to pages but can do anything documents what would that permisssion be?

Answer (score 1):

It is the contribute permission that you need.

If you want people to be able to contribute (add/modify/delete) documents, give them contribute permissions to the document library.  If you want them to not modify a page, make sure that they do not have contribute permissions to the page.

If you have the site setup off of a publishing template, pages are in a document library called "Pages" and you can ensure that these people do not have contribute permissions there.

If the site is not built off of a publishing template, just do not give the users "view" permissions to the site, then break inheritance on the document library and give them contribute permissions there.

Sorry for the stream-of-consciousness there... let me know if you need me to clarify :)